# Annotating satellite images in the field

Tags: polygon, image, satellite

I have high res satellite imagery of my remote field location through Planet. I am working with indigenous communities on participant action mapping and would like to be able to annotate my images in the field. I have a microsoft surface pro and would like to be able to draw polygons on the images, as well as add information to associate with each polygon such as, in the example of a farm site, what crops are being grown there, who works there, what methods are being used.

I can run GIS on this machine but I don't know if I can draw polygons with a stylus onto the map in GIS or add this data using GIS. Does anyone know if this is possible and if so how to do it? Or do you have any ideas for a different software that I can use to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arcgis online would be my first choice. Build an application with your images and a polygon feature layer. Then draw the polygons.

Comment: Thank you for your answer JCorona. Is it possible to do this with the ArcGIS desktop application? I won't have access to the internet at my field location

Comment: Yes, you'd simply load your images into arcmap. Then create a new polygon feature class and then enter your editing mode to draw your polygons. 

Sorry If I am misunderstanding the question. If you have any more and wish to reach me faster I'm on twitter @josiahcorona